# MSF for CMMI process in TFS 2013 - Feature x Requirement type = feature

Tags: cmmi, ms-solution-framework

Someone can explain to me why the MSF template for CMMI process have the option to create a **Feature** and a requirement of the type **feature**?

What's difference between the two options?

Answer (score 1):

Lucas,

In this case it's the terminology and not any intrinsic meaning.  In CMMI a feature is something someone wants built.  To build this feature, you will need to develop a set of requirements.  Then you can link requirements to a feature and then for each requirement you will have tasks that need to take place to implement the requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, I'm using exactly as you said, so the requirement of the type "feature", is never used?

Comment: I see what you are getting at.  Yes it is a little confusing in that you have features and then you have requirements which can be of the type feature as well as functional, business objective, operational, quality of service and so forth.  

My suggestion to you is to start simply and when your users say they want "things," think of them as features; one feature for each thing.  I am going this route because structuring my planning in this way lets me import to and from Microsoft Project as my rollup line items are features and their children are tasks.

-- continuing below.

Comment: Then after you have a higher level of understanding, you might want to create a requirement of type feature.  Make sense?